# add column stating the city the staff is from

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to  join some tables to show that 3 city columns can all be different for the same record. so far i've gotten

- the city the property is in
- the city of the branch that the property is from

the query is

```
select a.propertyNo, a.city as propertyCity, b.city
from PropertyForRent a
inner join Branch b on a.branchNo = b.branchNo
where a.ownerNo = 'CO69'
```

I need to get the city of the staff person, not the branch number and im not sure how to make it happen based on the branch number alone with the current query. I can achieve the answer as a query by itself. Im just not sure how to join it with the query above.

```
select branch.city, * from Staff
inner join Branch on staff.branchNo = branch.branchNo
where staff.staffNo = 'SA9'
```

[image: Here is a table diagram if it helps make more sense]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.propertyNo
, a.city as propertyCity
, b.city as propertyBranchCity
, sb.city as staffBranchCity
from PropertyForRent a
inner join Branch b on b.branchNo = a.branchNo
inner join Staff s on s.staffNo = a.staffNo
inner join Branch sb on sb.branchNo = s.branchNo
where a.ownerNo = 'CO69'
```

You're doing all the right things in your existing queries.

The issue you had may be that you need to pull data from the `staff` table that you don't display in results.  Note: you can use tables to allow you to create joins even if no fields from those tables are included in the output.

Or maybe your issue is you need to join to the `branch` table twice; once to get the property's branch, and a second time to get the staff member's branch. Note that you can join to the same table as many times as you like; just give each one a different alias (e.g. `b`, `sb` in the above example) so that you can distinguish between them.

Comment: Thanks
! the inner joining branch table twice worked. didn't think that was an option available to the query once it had already been joined

Answer (score 0):

use another join for PropertyForRent with your existing query

```
    select p.city  from Staff s
    inner join Branch b
   on s.branchNo = b.branchNo
   join  PropertyForRent p on p.branchNo=b.branchNo
   join  Branch bb  s.branchNo=bb.branchNo
    where staff.staffNo = 'SA9'
```